# SOLID Principle and GOF mapping

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, solid-principles

I am new to pattern and it is a newbiew question. I started looking SOLID principle recently and also on design patterns. After going through over view of both, I was wondering if there is any way we can define relationship between SOLID and design pattern at one place. example..

S - Pattern a, Pattern B

O - Patten c, d, e

L

I

D

Like wise, I think it will help to understand the principle and pattern better.

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design patterns can't really be assigned to one letter of the SOLID acronym. Design patterns actually help you (or at least they are supposed to!) design your software in a way that respects **all** five points of the SOLID principles. The principles are some sort of guideline you should keep in mind while doing object-oriented programming even if you are not using a design pattern.

With that said, there are indeed categories for design patterns. For example, the *gang of four* patterns fell into the categories [creational, structural and behavioral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Patterns_by_Type).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. When I read about SOLID and GOF pattern overview, I got into thinking, let say if need to think for "Single Responsibility Pattern" what all GOF pattern will fit into this category. I see what you are saying.

Answer (score 4):

I see SOLID as the foundations for patterns. There are many examples. Take your favorite GoF design pattern, and break it down with SOLID. Not all principles may apply, but it's a great way to understand the pattern.

For example, the Strategy pattern has concrete strategies:

[image: Strategy design pattern structure]

Each concrete strategy applies the **Single Responsibility Principle**. The Strategy hierarchy is **Open** for extensibility, while the Strategy interface is **Closed** to modification (so the clients remain stable). **Liskov** principle applies within Strategies, but maybe it's not a great example. **Interface segregation principle** is demonstrated by the single Strategy interface (as opposed to some interface with lots of methods). **Dependency inversion principle** is not so obvious, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a good relation to point :
Open Closed Principle implies Strategy Pattern.
Other than that Single Responsibility is applied in many of the design patterns .
Dependency Injection is related to MVC design pattern. 
But there is not really very direct relationships between GOF and SOLID

Answer (score 0):

Some of the GoF design patterns that help you implement OCP for example are template method (Through inheritance), Strategy or Decorator (Aggregation/Composition).